# How to avoid double encoding URI

Tags: ruby, encoding, uri

if a URL is not encoded, it causes problems later on, so I do

```
URI.encode(url)
```

problem is if the url is already encoded (for whatever reason), which further encodes the url making it unusable.

besides doing `URI.encode(URI.decode(url))`, is there a better way to ensure the url is encoded only once?

Answer (score 5):

There's no real way, you just need to keep track of whether the string is already URI-escaped or not. If you have a string that you have no idea if it's already URI-escaped or not, there's no good solution.

Generally you should be doing encoding at a single point in your code. In memory, all your strings should generally NOT be URI-escaped. You should unescape components immediately after parsing them from a URI. And when constructing URI's, only escape/encode them at the point of constructing a full URI.

You are out of luck at the point you have a string and have no idea if it's encoded or not; you need to keep track, ideally by making sure the encoding happens at clear system boundaries.

Comment: Or whenever you store a URI in a variable, explicitly state whether it is encorded or not. It is equivalent to the task of keeping track of units (Centigrade versus Fahrenheit, or kg versus lbs). If the variable name contains the units, such as `imageUrlEncoded`, you will always know whether to encode/decode or not.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:**

I'm updating my post since URI.encode/decode is deprecated in newer versions of Ruby.

```rb
uri = "www.example.com/%E5%86%99%E7%9C%9F/cats"

parser = URI::Parser.new
parser.escape(uri)

# => www.example.com/%25E5%2586%2599%25E7%259C%259F/cats

parser.unescape(parser.escape(uri))

# => www.example.com/%E5%86%99%E7%9C%9F/cats
```

I think it's worth it to create a wrapper URI class that handles this for you so that you don't have to do it every time. You can even do clever things like assuming the URI is parsed correctly, and if there's a parsing error trying to get it fully escaped and re-escape it.

```
def parse(str)
  begin
    uri = self.parser.parse(str)
  rescue URI::InvalidURIError => ex
    uri = self.parser.parse(self.parser.escape(str))
  end

  new(uri)
end
```

While this does work, in an ideal world you would parse URIs and they would be assumed to be encoded properly, and when building URIs making sure the components are properly encoded. Which is why when building URI objects, I prefer to escape each component indiv:

```rb
def build(args)
  # these things are not used by my application, so they're unnecessary
  userinfo, port, registry, opaque = nil

  scheme   = args[:scheme]
  host     = args[:host]
  path     = encoded_path(args[:path])
  query    = args[:query]
  fragment = args[:fragment]

  uri = URI::Generic.new(scheme, userinfo, host, port, registry, path, opaque, query, fragment)

  new(uri)
end
```

Where `encoded_path` just does a % encoding except for the path character set of `a-zA-Z\d_\.-~\/`.

When working with a URI object, it's common to modify the querystring before stringifying, so I opted to also have the querystring represented as a hash, with each value getting individually % encoded with `CGI.escape` when calling `to_s` on the uri object. This ensures things like nested URI objects as queyrstring values get escaped properly.

You can read more about % encoding and reserved characters from the [IETF website regarding RFC 3986](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-2.1).

All that being said, sometimes it's still impossible to know whether or not a URI is % encoded

**Original post:**

What's wrong with decoding a URI before encoding it? You sacrifice a little bit of performance for encoding safety:

```rb
uri = "www.example.com/%E5%86%99%E7%9C%9F/cats"

URI.encode(uri)

# => www.example.com/%25E5%2586%2599%25E7%259C%259F/cats

URI.encode(URI.decode(uri))

# => www.example.com/%E5%86%99%E7%9C%9F/cats
```

It's a little less than twice as slow as a simple encode, but it's *much* faster than the alternatives like `Addressable`.

Answer (score 2):

There's a duplicate of this question that has a partially valid answer by user [jordan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179125/jordan)

([Ruby - how to encode URL without re-encoding already encoded characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37592065/ruby-how-to-encode-url-without-re-encoding-already-encoded-characters)).

> `URI.escape` appears to work the way you want in all cases except when
>   characters are already encoded. With that in mind we can take the
>   result of `URI.encode` and use `String#gsub` to "un-encode" only those
>   characters.
>
> The below regular expression looks for `%25` (an encoded `%`) followed
>   by two hex digits, turning e.g. `%252f` back into `%2f`:
>
> ```
> require "uri"
>
> DOUBLE_ESCAPED_EXPR = /%25([0-9a-f]{2})/i
>
> def escape_uri(uri)
>   URI.encode(uri).gsub(DOUBLE_ESCAPED_EXPR, '%\1')
> end
>
> puts escape_uri("https://www.example.com/url-déjà-vu")
> # => https://www.example.com/url-d%C3%A9j%C3%A0-vu
> ```

It'a a bit klunky but it works for all the problem cases I have. Better yet, it's idempotent:

```
URI.encode("http://example.com/#example%example")
# => "http://example.com/%23example%25example"

URI.encode(URI.encode("http://example.com/#example%example"))
# => "http://example.com/%2523example%2525example"

escape_uri("http://example.com/#example%example")
# => "http://example.com/%23example%25example"

escape_uri(escape_uri("http://example.com/#example%example"))
# => "http://example.com/%23example%25example"
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Addressable](https://rubygems.org/gems/addressable/versions/2.4.0) gem often has the methods lacking in the URI library. In this case, Addressable::URI's `normalized_encode` method may do the trick:

```
weird = "https://www.example.com/this url’s weird"
# => "https://www.example.com/this url’s weird"

encoded = Addressable::URI.normalized_encode weird
# => "https://www.example.com/this%20url%E2%80%99s%20weird"

Addressable::URI.normalized_encode encoded
# => "https://www.example.com/this%20url%E2%80%99s%20weird"
```

References:
http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/addressable/2.3.5/Addressable/URI#normalized_encode-class_method

Comment: It's worth noting that `Addressable::URI.normaized_encode` is 9-10x slower than `URI.encode`. For larger apps that are looking for performance, Addressable is not the right gem.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure of a method included in OpenURI to do this, so just do a comparison with the [ternary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation) operator.

```
url == URI.encode(url) ? url : URI.encode(url)
```

It's easily readable and simple.

```
if_this_is_a_true_value ? then_the_result_is_this : else_it_is_this
```

There may be other ways, including checking the string for certain characters, etc. But I think for the sake of keeping things simple and readable, this is a decent solution.

Comment: This will not do anything useful. URI.encode is not idempotent. Often `url != URI.encode(url)` even if the url was already escaped/encoded. Which is exactly what leads to the double-encoding problem in the original question. In fact, your code is exactly equivalent to simply `URI.encode(url)`, the ternary you put in there will never change the output vs the simple original (try to find an example where it does).

Comment: That's very useful to know, thanks. I expected that there would be a difference to the string.

Comment: There is a difference to the string, even if it was already URI-encoded; that's why it won't work.